"Why does the Permissions-Policy header cause a 'Parse of permissions policy failed' error despite correct syntax?"
add_action('send_headers', function() {
header('Permissions-Policy: geolocation=(self), camera=(), microphone=(), fullscreen=(), clipboard-write=();');
}); - it is error Error with Permissions-Policy header: Parse of permissions policy failed because of errors reported by structured header parser.
add_action('send_headers', function() {
header( 'Permissions-Policy: geolocation=self, microphone=(), camera=(), interest-cohort=()' );
}); - it is good work not error in f12 open
